# htaccess redirection for multiple parameter URLs

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am new to ht-access 301 redirection.

Need to redirect **/old_movie.php?genre=release&category=new&language=English to /new_page.php?genre=release&category=new&language=English**

How to frame 301 redirection code,Please help

Note : the parameters are like below,
genre = release,old,2012,new2013,latest

category = similar to genre

language = English , German, Swedish etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just this rewrite rule will be good:

```
RewriteRule ^old_movie\.php$ /new_page.php [NC,L,R]
```

Query string will be automatically carried over to `new_page.php`.

Comment: thanks a lot. but the url in address bar still remains as  /old_movie.php?genre=release&category=new&language=English..